# bash is eating spaces from date format in linux

Tags: linux, bash, date

date format shows correct when i execute just date but when I store in a variable, loosing a space in date if it has single digit(need that extra space to grep /var/log/messages). please suggest to get the exact format as it is. thanks!

```
$date -d '-1 day' '+%b %e'
Aug  1
$echo $(date -d '-1 day' '+%b %e')
Aug 1
$var=`date -d '-1 day' '+%b %e'`
$echo $var
Aug 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use double-quotes like this:

```
$ echo $(date -d '+1 day' '+%b %e')
Aug 2
$ echo "$(date -d '+1 day' '+%b %e')"
Aug  2
```

Or:

```
$ var="$(date -d '+1 day' '+%b %e')"
$ echo $var
Aug 2
$ echo "$var"
Aug  2
```

Without double-quotes, the shell, among other things, applies *word splitting* to the output and that collapses multiple spaces to one blank.